# Plot path that overlaps itself marking overlappings

Tags: javascript, svg, plot, svg.js

I'm trying to plot the [trefoil knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot) parametrized like in its wiki, using `svg.js` (but I can change the tool if it's necessary). The problem is that I can't achieve marking the zones where it overlaps like is done [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TrefoilKnot_01.svg).

I want to think the person that did that example plotted it in a smart way avoiding to deal with each of those spaces one by one, because otherwise doing something like that svg would be a bit expensive (in relation of time) if you need to change of model (or just another knot).

Does anyone know how was it done or was it solved *by hand* dealing with each space one by one?

Comment: If you take a look at the [code](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/TrefoilKnot_01.svg) you'll see that is using 6 paths: 3 for the black knot and 3 for the white one.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea would be to mask the interruptions. For DRY code, define the rendered path first as templates for reuse.

```css
path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
}
mask rect {
    fill: white;
}
.shadow {
    stroke-width: 20;
}
.knot {
    stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg style="width:100px;" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <!-- path templates for multiple use -->
    <path id="lower" d="M10 10 90 90" />
    <path id="higher" d="M10 90 90 10" />
    <mask id="mask">
      <!-- white background: everything is visible -->
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" />
      <!-- black line: masked out space for higher path -->
      <use href="#higher" class="shadow" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <!-- lower path with masked-out gap -->
  <use href="#lower" mask="url(#mask)" class="knot" />
  <!-- higher path uninterrupted -->
  <use href="#higher" class="knot" />
</svg>
```

Comment: [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).